# 3d wave front object coordinate data from multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, 3d, wavefront

Hi i made a simple script (algorithm) to parse a wavefront object file with php .i can extract the 3d coordinate of each vertex an assign them into an array i have array $y,$x,$z of each vertex.
my goal is to create a cube of vertex around the main coordinates, so i took the negative and the positive coordinates of each axis turn them into an absolute value an divided them by a distance of separation .

eg :

```
   $separator =  02.0000  ;
   $z_minus   = -23.3344  ;
   $z_plus    =  13.3445  ;
   $z_length  =  abs($z_minus) + abs($z_plus);
   $number_of_vertex_z =  $z_length/$separator;
```

the same process give me the $number_of_vertex for each axis .from that i can use a loop to create the x,y,z coordinates of new points to form a cube of points around my 3d shape .
my end goal will be to keep only the points that are within 02.0000 of the original 3d obj its a form of triangulation i will like to have some advice on how to do it efficiently.

it is important for me to form a cube first then extract the end points because i want the result object to be a subdivided version of the original made out of equal size rectangular faces similar to gcode for 3d printing but in my case my object will be made out of multiple little square faces.

thanks i hope my goal is clear enough.